# Admin pages have no content

Tags: admin, wp-admin, admin-menu, admin-bar

Not the usual white screen of whatever horror, my site is shown normally until you go to the admin dashboard. While the dashboard (or the admin menu if you will) is visible and responds accordingly, the content is not shown for any of the sections/pages.

Except for one two things: adding a post and editing an old one. And so, this is what I get:

http://dumpt.com/img/files/jdyvf8206fkmi1w01e6u.png

The page update animation just rolls and rolls without any actual changes even made. Haven't found any discussions about the said problem anywhere so... Need help :D

Comment: You should check out the Dev Tools Console for any JavaScript errors(I`m sure there are some, from the way things look like in the screenshot).

Answer (score 1):

Try going to Tools then Export and export your Wordpress site into an XML file. Then delete your Wordpress site off your web server and reinstall it. Go Tools > Import and click on import and select the XML file. Reinstalling Wordpress should fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

This all because of PHP has been allocated less memory.
So have to increase PHP memory limit.If PHP has been allocated 64MB, there is no need to set this value to 64M as WordPress will automatically use all 64MB if need be.
Increase PHP Memory to add this line to wp-config.php file.

```
define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '96M');
```

if it works then let me know.

Comment: I did this and reloaded the admin menu page. Nothing happened, unfortunately. But thanks for the initiative, I sure hope some other will stumble upon this problem too as I still can't find anything related to this by searching Google.